# How is Task.Run limited by CPU cores?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Why is it that the following program will only run a limited number of blocked tasks. The limiting number seems to be the number of cores on the machine.

Initially when I wrote this I expected to see the following:

- Job complete output of Jobs 1 - 24
- A 2 second gap
- Output of Jobs 25 - 48

However the output was:

- Job complete output of Jobs 1 - 4
- Then randomly completing jobs every couple of 100ms.

When running on server with 32 cores, the program did run as I had expected.

```
class Program
{
    private static object _lock = new object();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int completeJobs = 1;
        var limiter = new MyThreadLimiter();
        for (int iii = 1; iii < 100000000; iii++)
        {
            var jobId = iii;
            limiter.Schedule()
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        completeJobs++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Job: " + completeJobs + " scheduled");
                    }
                });
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class MyThreadLimiter
{
    readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(24);

    public async Task Schedule()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

        Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000))
            .ContinueWith(t => _semaphore.Release());
    }
}
```

However replacing the Thread.Sleep with Task.Delay gives my expected results.

```
    public async Task Schedule()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

        Task.Delay(2000)
            .ContinueWith(t => _semaphore.Release());
    }
```

And using a `Thread` gives my expected results

```
    public async Task Schedule()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            _semaphore.Release();
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
```

How does `Task.Run()` work? Is it the case it is limited to the number of cores?

Comment: Don't use `Task.Run` for blocking code. It's designed for running CPU-bound tasks. You're seeing the results of the thread pool trying to deal with your misuse :) If you want to *simulate* a CPU-bound task, `Thread.Sleep` may be useful for some scenarios, but a busy-loop would be closer to reality (in particular, it will actually use the CPU, rather than blocking the thread).

Comment: Yeah I guess starting a Thread is better here. The actual use for this structure was to pull messages of a rabbitmq queue and process them concurrently. The class creating the thread doesn't actually know what the processing does. I was hoping by setting the limit on the semaphore the consumer can set a limit, based on whether it knows it is CPU intensive or mainly network calls.

Comment: If your RabbitMQ API has asynchronous methods, use those - that's exactly what they're for. The basic idea is that a thread is only used when necessary, and for the I/O itself (which would normally be blocking), you just get control back when the request is finished. Thanks to `await`, this is almost as simple as doing synchronous I/O. Throttling is always a bit complicated :) Note that `SemaphoreSlim` also has an async API, so even that doesn't need you to waste threads doing nothing.

Comment: How many cores did you have at that time? the thread pool starts with a minimum number of threads which is equal to the number of the cores so if you had 4 cores then it does make sense to get the result 1 - 4 and then randomly every X amount of milliseconds to get a new job completed as the thread pool needs to create new threads  due to blocking the existing threads using thread.sleep which task.dealy does not do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Task.Run` schedules the work to run in the thread pool.  The thread pool is given wide latitude to schedule the work as best as it can in order to maximize throughput.  It will create additional threads when it feels they will be helpful, and remove threads from the pool when it doesn't think it will be able to have enough work for them.

Creating more threads than your processor is able to run at the same time isn't going to be productive when you have CPU bound work.  Adding more threads will just result in dramatically more context switches, increasing overhead, and reducing throughput.

Comment: Also some good info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx Threards are somewhat expensive to create and take 1 MB memory for stack; but the thread pool creates new threads when it runs out at a rate of about 1 a second.

Comment: I see, so given that Thread.Sleep is blocking does that mean that Threadpool thinks running more threads would perform worse? Given that in the trivial example shown above using Thread start is more productive this seems wrong. By more productive I mean getting to 24 complete jobs is quicker when creating threads manually.

Comment: @NickWilliams The thread pool assumes that you're not scheduling lots and lots of threads that are going to sit there doing nothing.  It assumes that you're going to schedule lots of jobs that actually do CPU bound work, because that's what it's there to do.  Creating a whole bunch of full threads just to have all of them sit there doing nothing is *extremely* wasteful of system resources.  The correct solution, if you don't actually have any work to do, is to not create any threads at all, as you show in one of your solutions.

Comment: The Thread.Sleep was and example so people could quickly run a sample. The actual use for this structure is to pull messages off a rabbitmq queue and process them concurrently. The work being done to process the messages is not really CPU bound, most time is spent making network and database calls. The network and database calls are blocking. So creating threads manually does produce better performance. Perhaps as @Luaan said Task.Run is should be used in this situation?

Comment: @NickWilliams If you don't have CPU bound work to be doing, then you shouldn't be using `Task.Run`, nor is there a reason for you to be creating new threads.  Use inherently asynchronous methods for your database interactions, and then `await` those tasks.  They then won't need *any* thread to do their work.

Comment: I guess I don't understand my own problem enough. Given this answers the question about my sample application I will ask a new question about the rabbitmq implementation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285680/handle-rabbitmq-messages-concurrenrtly

Comment: @NickWilliams No, the threadpool sees that the threads aren't doing any CPU work, so it slowly starts spinning up new threads (and when they're done, slowly tear them down again). But it's still designed for CPU work - blocking on a threadpool thread is a mistake, and the threadpool just tries to help you around your mistake. If you wanted to use the threadpool for blocking code, you could just change the default threadpool size - that would make it work better than manual threads again for your scenario. But it's pointless - use asynchronous I/O instead of blocking :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes for compute bound operations `Task.Run()` internally uses CLR's thread pool which will throttle the number of new threads to avoid CPU over-subscription. Initially it will run the number of threads that equals to the number of cpu cores concurrently. Then it continually optimises the number of threads using a hill-climbing algorithm based on factors like the number of requests thread pool receives and overall computer resources to either create more threads or fewer threads.

In fact, this is one of the main benefits of using pooled thread over raw thread e.g. (`new Thread(() => {}).Start()`) as it not only recycles threads but also optimises performance internally for you. As mentioned in the other answer, it's generally a bad idea to block pooled threads because it will "mislead" thread pool's optimisation, simiarly using many pooled thread to do very long-running computation can also lead to thread pool creating more threads and consequently increase the overheads of context switch and later destory extra threads in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

The Task.Run() is running based on CLR Thread pool.
There is a concept called 'OverSubscription', means there 
are being more active thread than CPU Cores and they must be time-sliced.
In Thread-Pool when the number of threads that must be scheduled on CPU Cores
increase, Context-Switch rise and at the result, the performance will hurt.
The CLR that manages the Thread-Pool avoid OverSubscription by queuing 
and throttling the thread startup and always try to compensate workload.