# Handle rabbitmq messages concurrenrtly

Tags: c#, multithreading, rabbitmq

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277862/how-is-task-run-limited-by-cpu-cores/) about why starting a process using Thread.Run did not execute as many concurrent requests as I expected.

The reason behind this question was that I was trying to create a class which can pull messages off a rabbitmq queue and process them concurrently up to a maximum number of concurrent messages.

To do this I ended up with the following in the `Received` handler of the `EventingBasicConsumer` class.

```
async void Handle(EventArgs e) 
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Process(e);
        _semaphore.Release(); 
        _channel.BasicAck(....);
    });
    thread.Start();
}
```

However the comments on the previous post were not to start a thread unless doing CPU bound work.

The above handler does not know whether the work will be CPU bound, Network, Disk or otherwise. (`Process` is an abstract method).

Even so I think I have to start a thread or task here, otherwise the `Process` method blocks the rabbitmq thread and the event handler is not called again until it is finished. So I can only handle one method at once.

Is starting a new `Thread` here okay? Originally I had used `Task.Run` but this didn't produce as many workers as wanted. See other post.

FYI. The number of concurrent threads is capped by setting the `InitialCount` on the semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

As already been said in linked question, big number of threads doesn't guarantee the performance, as if their number gets more than the number of logical cores, you got a [thread starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)) situation with no real work being done.

However, if you still need to handle the number of a concurrent operations, you may give a try to the `TPL Dataflow` library, with settings up the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx), like in [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609.aspx).

```
var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<EventArgs>(
    // Process event
    e => Process(e),
    // Specify a maximum degree of parallelism.
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = InitialCount
    });
var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock();
// link the blocks for automatically propagading the messages
bufferBlock.LinkTo(workerBlock);

// asynchronously send the message
await bufferBlock.SendAsync(...);
// synchronously send the message
bufferBlock.Post(...);
```

`BufferBlock` is a queue, so the order of messages will be preserved. Also, you can add the different handlers (with a different degree of parallelism) with linking the blocks with filter lambda:

```
bufferBlock.LinkTo(cpuWorkerBlock, e => e is CpuEventArgs);
bufferBlock.LinkTo(networkWorkerBlock, e => e is NetworkEventArgs);
bufferBlock.LinkTo(diskWorkerBlock, e => e is DiskEventArgs);
```

but in this case you should setup a default handler at the end of the chain, so the message wouldn't disappear (you may use a [`NullTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462765.aspx) block for this):

```
bufferBlock.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<EventArgs>);
```

Also, the block could be an observers, so they perfectly work with [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985.aspx) on UI side.